# How can I create a single dictionary from a text file that contains multiple individual JSON strings?

Tags: python, json

I have a dataset:

```
{ "source_table": "College", "action": "INSERT", "timestamp": "001", "name": "UT", "status": "1" }
{ "source_table": "Major",  "action": "INSERT", "timestamp": "003", "name": "Engineering"}
{ "source_table": "Class", "action": "UPDATE", "timestamp": "003", "name": "Freshman", "status": "1" }
{ "source_table": "Student", "action": "INSERT", "timestamp": "004", "state": "CA", "status": "1" }
{ "source_table": "Student", "action": "UPDATE", "timestamp": "007", "state": "TX", "status": "2" }
```

My question is, since these are individually formatted strings, can they be loaded into a single dictionary? Or do they have to be sorted into different dictionaries, with each having the correct number of key/value pairs - i.e., ***college*** would source_table, action, timestamp, name, and status while ***student*** would have source_table, action, timestamp, state, and status?

I can read the file as a txt file (which it is - but is that correct?) Or does it need to be parsed as JSON from the txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do them line by line.  Like this:

```
import json
data = []
for line in open('file.json'):
    data.append( json.loads(line) )
```

Or:

```
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('file.json')]
```

Comment: so I had tried something like this, but when I go back to check and do print(data), I only return the first line?

Comment: even when I do this and try:

`key_list = list(data.keys()) print(key_list)`

it still only shows the first line's worth of json

Comment: I committed a rookie mistake.  It needs an `append` in the loop, not an `=`.

Comment: this might be unrelated, but when i try to print all the values in my dictionary now (that worked) as `list_values = list(data.values())  print(list_values)`, it doesn't work to print the values - shouldn't this now have created a dictionary where every preceding value from the appended json would be the key, while the following value is the matching key value?

Comment: No, it creates a list of dictionaries, because that's what's in the file.  If you want it reorganized to a single dictionary with "source_table" as the key, you can certainly do that, but that doesn't reflect the file.